# Cannot start Cygnus with 2 instances as a service

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I have configured 2 cygnus intances with their agents but when I start cygnus as a service I get the following error:

```
sudo service cygnus start
Starting cygnus (via systemctl):  Job for cygnus.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status cygnus.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Also when I run the `"systemctl status cygnus.service"` command I get this output:

```
[root@orion conf]# systemctl status cygnus.service
● cygnus.service - SYSV: cygnus
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cygnus; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-09-16 00:01:02 UTC; 18s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 14719 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cygnus start (code=exited, status=2)

Sep 16 00:01:00 orion.novalocal cygnus[14719]: rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/cygnus/cygnus_1.pid’: No such file or directory
Sep 16 00:01:00 orion.novalocal su[14766]: (to cygnus) root on none
Sep 16 00:01:00 orion.novalocal cygnus[14719]: Starting Cygnus test...  bash: /var/run/cygnus/cygnus_test.pid: No such file or directory
Sep 16 00:01:02 orion.novalocal cygnus[14719]: cat: /var/run/cygnus/cygnus_test.pid: No such file or directory
Sep 16 00:01:02 orion.novalocal cygnus[14719]: [FAILED]
Sep 16 00:01:02 orion.novalocal cygnus[14719]: rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/cygnus/cygnus_test.pid’: No such file or directory
Sep 16 00:01:02 orion.novalocal systemd[1]: cygnus.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
Sep 16 00:01:02 orion.novalocal systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: cygnus.
Sep 16 00:01:02 orion.novalocal systemd[1]: Unit cygnus.service entered failed state.
Sep 16 00:01:02 orion.novalocal systemd[1]: cygnus.service failed.
```

There seems to be problem with the pid files at `/var/run/cygnus/` path.
Also these are the 2 configured instances:
cygnus_instance_test.conf:

```
CYGNUS_USER=cygnus
CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_test.conf
AGENT_NAME=cygnus-ngsi
LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log
ADMIN_PORT=8081
POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

cygnus_instance_1.conf:

```
CYGNUS_USER=cygnus
CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf
AGENT_NAME=cygnus-ngsi
LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log
ADMIN_PORT=8081
POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have a /var/run/cygnus directory